# Where should you store a lot of custom Strings in RoR?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a portal model. Every user gets their own portal. Now the user can customize various strings across multiple pages on that portal to show their customers. Overall there are around 50 strings and an average user changes from defaults to around 7 of them.

One way to go about is to use a table per page and push strings for a page to that table as columns and map those tables to the portal. However, this would create 5 additional tables, models and corresponding management of forms. Also, these would be very sparse tables.

Is there a better way for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why have a separate table for each page?  It's very likely that terms will be shared across pages and when you add a new page to the app you will then have to add a new table??!!

My preference would just to have one table with the 'term' being the value used in your html and the other being the user preference

`table user_strings (
  user_id int not null
  term varchar not null
  val varchar not null
  primary key(user_id, term)
  foreign key (user_id) references user(id) on delete cascade
  index (term)
)`

If you are not using composite primary keys, then add a the default id